# Drupal 7 - Passing Arguments from Page Manager/Panel to embedded view/reference field

Tags: nodes, panels, views

Drupal 7: I try to pass an argument (eg node:title) from panels/page manager to use as filter criteria in an embedded view.In the view I want to fetch this argument as a filter criteria to a reference field.

In Panels I can define pass arguments, but how can I fetch and compare them in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to pass contexts from panels to a view. If that's the case, see my answer on [Send a context from a panel page to a view integrated in it?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8697)

If you want to pass arguments (dynamically added by changing the URL to your panels page) to a view, then in the view panes settings, make sure to check `Send arguments`. You can then access the arguments in the view using Contextual Filters as if it were a regular views page.

Answer (score 0):

Make a display in your view of type "panel pane" and place this pane into your panel instead of the block/master view you were using.

This will allow you MUCH more control over how your arguments are pulled/pushed into the view (from context/defined on pane config/fixed, etc). They will then be available directly in contextual filters as usual.

Post any issues you run into and i can help.